# +CMS ERROR: 304, sending message using at command

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem, pdu

Im new to GSM and AT command sets,

based on the error +CMS ERROR: 304 its a **Invalid PDU mode parameter** according to [activexperts](http://www.activexperts.com/activsms/sms/gsmerrorcodes/)

Im trying to send message using AT command to GSM modem in PDU mode

```
AT+CMGF=0
OK

AT+CMGS=31
> 079136190700203911000C913639350768260000AA13C834A89D07B9C3ED32283D0751C3F3F41B

+CMS ERROR: 304
```

Can you help me guys what did I missed or mistake?  [I used this to encode the PDU](http://www.smartposition.nl/resources/sms_pdu.html)

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try by chaning PDU mode. Use the following command:

```
AT + CMGF = 1
```

If you are trying to Send SMS try `AT + CMGF = 1` first and then again  `AT+CMGS="NUMBER"` and hope after typing the message on `> prompt`, you are using `CTRL+Z` key combination to send SMS.

Comment: Thanks mate for giving me a clue that I didn't <CTRL+Z>

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hitting **ENTER** after placing the PDU, use **CTRL-Z** to send message.

credits to @user2543882